# jni loadlibrary, findLibrary returns null

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have already checked the existing questions on SO. I am a first time asker but always look for my problems here and usually find the solutions to them. This time I couldn't.

I'm trying to use echoprint's audio fingerprinting api and I have implemented the code successfully. But when I execute it I get this error:

```
        07-28 19:50:05.910: E/AndroidRuntime(23067): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-15102
        07-28 19:50:05.910: E/AndroidRuntime(23067): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
Couldn't load echoprint-jni from loader    dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.realapptest1-2.apk,
    libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.realapptest1-2]: findLibrary returned null
```

I do not really know how to solve this issue. The api folder comes with a "jni" folder if that helps. But I have literally no idea what else I am supposed to do.

As can be assumed I am using the Eclipse IDE. There are no errors in my application. I have proof checked it, there are no problems in my code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html)

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: Thrown when an attempt is made to invoke a native for which an implementation could not be found.
```

Your app tries to call a native library and does not find it. Make sure that the native library is build and that you call

```
System.loadLibrary("your-library-name");
```

before you use it.

You can read more about Android Ndk [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#GetStarted).

Also, here's a good tutorial that will make the Ndk easier to understand: [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvCRlJToCAg)